# Reference an element by href hash without using jQuery

Tags: javascript

Say I have an element `<a href="/foo#bookmark">`. I want to reference this element by its hash, which I can do using jQuery. How would I do this only using JavaScript?

Example code:

```
<a id="foo" href="/foo#bookmark" onclick="exampleFunction(this)">Some text</a>

<script>
/**
 * @param {Element} el
 */
function exampleFunction(el) {
    let bookmarkHash = el.hash,
        $bookmarkElement = jQuery(bookmarkHash);

    console.info($bookmarkElement.offset().top);
}
</script>
```

Here `jQuery(bookmarkHash)` references the original `<a>` so I can get the offset of the element. How can I do this in pure JavaScript?

Comment: You're passing in the element to the fuction, just use `$bookmarkElement = $(el);`

Comment: I don't want to use jQuery at all.

Comment: @ebakunin you are still passing the element in, aren't you? Why do you need to reference the element by it's hash when you _already have it_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script `jQuery(bookmarkHash);` jquery is only returning a selector. So you can swap that out easily.

```js
/**
 * @param {Element} el
 */
function exampleFunction(el) {
    let bookmarkHash = el.hash,
        $bookmarkElement = document.querySelector(bookmarkHash);

  /* you will need to figure out the elements offset bit */
    console.info($bookmarkElement);
}
```

```html
<a id="foo" href="#bookmark" onclick="exampleFunction(this)">Some text</a>
<div id="bookmark">Hello</div>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector(bookmarkHash)` is what I was looking for. I did not explain my problem well. Thanks for getting me the answer anyway!

Comment: Glad I could help.